# free $S^1$ action on $\mathbb{R}P^n$ and $\mathbb{C}P^n$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, group-actions

I want to construct free $S^1$ action on $\mathbb{R}P^n$ and $\mathbb{C}P^n$.

For $n=2m-1$, consider $S^n ⊂ C^m$. Then $S^1$ freely act on $S^n$ by  $(ξ, (z_1 , z _2 , · · · , z _m )) → (ξz_1 , ξz_2 , · · · , ξz_m )$ where  $ξ ∈ S^1 $. Then $S^1/\mathbb{Z}_2\cong S^1$  will act freely on $\mathbb{R}P^n = S^n /\mathbb{Z}_2$.

I want to know what are all other free $S^1$ action on $\mathbb{R}P^n$?

Also How to construct a free $S^1$ action on $\mathbb{C}P^n$?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: The Euler characteristic of $RP^{2n}$ and $CP^n$ are nonzero, so every vector field vanishes somewhere. So they have no free $S^1$-action. It remains to classify free $S^1$-action on $S^{2m-1}$.

Comment: @YCor Thank you.I did not know this fact. It will be very helpful if you kindly elaborate your answer.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincare-Hopf_theorem. It works in the smooth case. I guess it's still true in the topological context that a connected topological manifold (or even a finite CW-complex?) with a free continuous action of the circle group has zero Euler characteristic, but this requires another argument.

Comment: @YCor Sorry I didn’t understand how vanishing of every vector field is related to non  existence of free S^1 action?

Comment: Let $f:(t,x)\mapsto tx=f(t,x)$ be the free action, $t\in S^1$, $x\in X$, and consider the vector field $x\mapsto\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,x)$.

Comment: @sneharoychoudhary As I commented on the same post on MSE. Here is a proof https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284292/does-there-exist-any-non-contractible-manifold-with-fixed-point-property

Comment: In view of @YCor's sage comment, this question becomes a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18569/circle-action-on-sphere

Comment: @IgorRivin Thank you for the reference